# Изменение даты в медиатеке

Tags: wordpress

Помогите решить проблемку - как массово изменить дату загрузки медиафайлов на основе каталога?

Готовый плагин или код - не важно.

При импорте контента картинки раскидались правильно, по своим каталогам, но дата присвоилась текущая. Например файл лежит в /2020/04/, однако его дата в медиатеке - июль 2021, когда был импорт контента.

[image]

Comment: там и написано "ЗАГРУЖЕНО". Когда загружено, такая и дата. Это не дата файла, это дата загрузки.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо КЭП. Вопрос  в том, как изменить эту дату.

Comment: Не слишком вежливо если рассчитываете получить ответ. Попробуйте [Media Library Assistant](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/)

Comment: @Simon спасибо, но он не умеет массово менять даты, только по одному.

Comment: Тогда проще сделать SQL запросом.

Comment: @Simon, я с этим и прошу помощи.